# socket hang up when I add a meteor package

Tags: sockets, meteor

I was so upset when I want to add some meteor package.I have meet this questions many times, can anyone helps me.

I am using ubuntu 14.04

> hehe@hehe-P45VJ:~/Mycode/meteor/microscope$ meteor add accounts-password
>
> => Errors while adding packages:
>
> While downloading npm-bcrypt@0.7.8_2...:
>
> error: socket hang up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a firewall somewhere blocking the connection we saw this in some areas in china, when we were not using a vpn. Check your connection with another machine to confirm.